# Clustering Data majority is 0

Tags: r, clustering

I am performing a cluster analysis with a 4K by 200+ table and my data mostly looks like this:

```
item1   item2 item3 item4
 21      35    0     17
  0      0     0     0
  0      0     23    0
  0      32    0     0
  0      0     0     0
 34      0     0     0
```

Majority are zero's, and because of that I can't create a proper clustering. Should I remove some data or perform factor analysis. I am using R.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using *hierarchical clustering* with an appropriate metric such as Cosine similarity, which can handle 0 values much better.

But in the end, **first figure out how to measure similarity**, then cluster.